# Shouldn't conflict of interest disclaimers be required ipso facto as opposed to after the fact?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question is the basis of my question:

[Is an electric circuit patentable?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/is-an-electric-circuit-patentable)

A new user shows up (no history for any pattern), presume, there is no pattern of a particular material having been repeatedly suggested; how could we tell it is not merely soliciting or advertising?

A few general SE rules come to my mind:

- Be *especially* nice to new users, and help them find their way around;
- An answer (or question) must be self-contained, links must be used only for permitting independent verification of a fact or law, and in support of the self-contained post.

Based on this, I would say with a warm welcoming first, the second rule should be applied, and expansive links should be edited out.

But if, for any reason, it must stay, then maybe a rule of conflict disclaimer should be required to re-enter a link even when the answer is self-contained.

If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the site adopting a rule along those lines that a new poster is unlikely to know when first participating. In the specific case I did not see evidence of blatant, un-acknowledged, self promotion.